# Output to the screen and file recording from function postgresql

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, solaris, postgresql-8.4

There is a function stub (I need to parallelize it, having separated input data for it on part and to cause it on dataful different computers from these parts)

```
-- Function: net_train(text[], integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net_train(terms text[], perceptron_id integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$begin
-- stub
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer) IS 'Comment: Train the Kohonen Neural Network with input data
Params:
 text[] terms - array of terms, on which net is train
 int perceptron_id - ID of perceptron to be added
```

Whether but to check really it was executed it is necessary to insert some actions in it, namely me responses to 2 questions interest:

1. How to display some message from this function? (it would be desirable to see an example)
2. If to assume, what before a call of this function the `/etc/perceptron_id.txt` file (this function parameter has the integer type and in this case string representation of this number means) how from this function to realize adding in this already created file of each element of an input array of `terms text []` on one for every line (beforehand having opened the above file for adding of lines) is already created? (it would be desirable to see an example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean by outputting to the screen.  These functions return values to the sql query executor, not the screen.  You can raise notices or return results that the wrapping program can then display to the screen however.  Something like:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Config file updated';
```

Now to do something like updating a file, you'd probably want to do something like:

```
COPY perceptron(id) TO '/etc/percetron_id.txt' WITH csv;
```

Otherwise you want to use a wrapper function.

Note that these sorts of things are not transactional.  You can't roll back a write to a file outside the database, so I would recommend having another program pull the results and write the file rather than doing so directly in the backend.  `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` are great for that.